# How do I get the fit-to-content width of a JavaFX TableColumn?

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8

When I create a JavaFX `TableView`, by default the columns are sized to the content. However, when I get the preferred size property of each column, it's a fixed value. How is the "content size" calculated, and is there a property that exposes it?

For example, the code below:

```
public class TableExample extends Application {

  private static <R, V> TableColumn<R, V> makeColumn(String name, Function<R, V> value) {
    TableColumn<R, V> col = new TableColumn<>(name);
    col.setCellValueFactory((param) ->
      new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(value.apply(param.getValue())));
    return col;
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    TableView<String> table = new TableView<>();
    ObservableList<String> items = table.getItems();
    items.addAll("Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "Qux", "Quux", "Corge", "Grault");
    ObservableList<TableColumn<String, ?>> columns = table.getColumns();
    columns.add(makeColumn("#", items::indexOf));
    columns.add(makeColumn("value", Function.identity()));
    columns.add(makeColumn("hash", Object::hashCode));

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    root.setCenter(table);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    for (TableColumn<String, ?> col : columns) {
      System.out.printf("%s: pref = %f, actual = %f%n", col.getText(), col.getPrefWidth(), col.getWidth());
    }
  }
}
```

This generates:

[image: table example]

And outputs:

```
#: pref = 80.000000, actual = 28.226563
value: pref = 80.000000, actual = 55.419434
hash: pref = 80.000000, actual = 97.002930
```

Note that the preferred widths are all the same, whereas the actual widths are appropriate to the content.

It's not enough for me to get the actual values at a given point in time, because the columns could be resized manually or the content could change. I want to know how those values are calculated, and how I can get at the result of that calculation.

Comment: Probably it's done using the `prefWidth` on some cells after filling them for the first time. You probably need to go through the source code of [`TableViewSkin`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/skin/TableViewSkin.html) to get the exact details though...

Comment: a) the cells are measured (where/how exactly is version dependent) b) there is no api to expose the result